# PromptValidator not being utilized, error thrown in ChoiceExtractor instead

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I am trying to use a `PromptValidator` within a `ConfirmPrompt`. Certain non yes/no responses to the prompt throw a `NullReferenceException` error within `Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.Choice.ChoiceExtractor`. Here's my stack trace:
https://gist.github.com/MilesWilde/be7eae75c8e0458454823a7ce6dcb484

I can recreate this issue by uploading a .gif file to the chat whenever I get a `ConfirmPrompt`. Here's how I've set up within my dialog to allow this validator:

```
dialogs.Add(new ConfirmPrompt("minutesConfirmationPrompt", DialogValidators.ConfirmValidatorAsync));
```

I've tested this within the emulator and my `DialogValidators.ConfirmValidatorAsync` validator does not get breakpointed at all, so it seems like there's something going on with an internal service. This also happens in production code. I'd prefer it if I got my reprompt message rather than an error here. Any tips?

Comment: I see you asked this 3 months ago. Was wondering if you found a solution by now or not

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet, but haven't been actively looking. This is pretty low priority for now.